# Apache Cordova Facebook Plugin BUILD FAILED

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova, ant

I am trying to install the facebook cordova plugin using the cordova CLI but unfortunately, whatever I do, I get BUILD FAILED whenever I try to `cordova build android`.

This is what I am using to install the plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="my_facebook_app_id" --variable APP_NAME="my_facebook_app_name"
```

Of course, I use my real facebook App_ID and App_Name. I also put them in `plugin.xml` everywhere there is APP_NAME or APP_ID. I don't know how to get older cmd error logs, because the only errors I see when the buld fails are error occuring because of a previous error. I tried `cordova build android -d` but it didn't help at all.

I don't know if it has something to do with my cordova version or with the fact that I already have other plugins and have developed quite a lot and my app is no longer as empty as the example one.

Cordova version: 3.5.0-0.2.6

P.S.: Just tried it on a new cordova build of my version, same error. I wonder how everybody else is not getting any, obviously the error is in me or the cordova version ;(

Comment: Do you think this is the same issue as mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837802/how-can-i-install-the-facebookconnect-cordova-plugin

Comment: Yep, I think this is the same error. I really hope you need to use facebook just for simple login and sharing. If this is your case, you could simply use [this](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB) plugin like I did, read the facebook documentation and create your own custom requests. If you encounter any errors in the process, message me and I can maybe help you, as I encountered and solved many myself while using cordova and facebook.

Comment: Thank you very much for the offer. I did get it to work though (go check out my question again, I've added the answer).